# Os cabelos são loiros ou louros?

Tags: ortografia, regionalismo, informalidade

Ambos estão corretos? Existe uma contexto para cada uso? Tem a ver com regionalismo ou informalidade?

Há alguma fonte confiável que indique isto?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As duas formas estão corretas.

"Louro" é a forma mais antiga, enquanto "loiro" foi registrado pela primeira vez em 1836.
Por volta dessa época e anterior, era comum várias palavras terem "ou" onde hoje se fala "oi", como "cousa", "doudo", etc. Com o passar do tempo foi ficando mais comum usar a forma com "oi", porém algumas palavras permaneceram ambas as formas, como no caso de "louro" e "loiro".

O quão comum cada uma é utilizada depende da região. Então no fim acaba sendo nada mais do que duas formas diferentes para a mesma palavra.

[Fonte](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/consultorio/qual-e-a-forma-correta-louro-ou-loiro/) (achei válida, não sei se considera confiável).

Comment: Já li uma vez um texto do início do século 20 (acho que era de 1903) e ao longo do texto, em várias ocasiões aparecia a palavra "dous" ao invés de "dois".

Comment: A resposta está certa, embora a fonte definitivamente não seja confiável ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto Também achei que não era a mais adequada, mas foi a que eu achei, e a mais completa.

Comment: @BrunoLopes podes retirar a primeira frase. Em Portugal é igual, louro/loiro, ouro/oiro, louça/loiça todas são corretas, embora umas se usem mais que as outras.

Comment: @Jorge Removi. Eu tinha colocado porque pode acontecer de eu afirmar alguma coisa que não é verdade em outro dialeto, então para evitar isso eu especifiquei que me refiro ao português brasileiro, mas obrigado pelo feedback.

Answer (score 7):

Ambas as formas estão corretas; há de facto um grande grupo de palavras que possuem o ditongo *ou*, podendo este ser substituído por *oi*. Exemplos são palavras como *touro*/*toiro*, *ouro*/*oiro*, *dourado*/*doirado*, etc. Esta segunda forma para estas palavras é relativamente mais recente que a forma com *ou*; talvez a língua esteja a evoluir para que todas as palavras que se escrevem atualmente com *ou* passem a ser escritas com *oi* - isto já aconteceu com algumas palavras, como *dois*. Parece-me mais comum ouvir a primeira forma, mas ambas estão corretas.