# "uvas douradas" or "uvas doiradas"?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas

I was listening to a traditional Portuguese song ("Uma Casa Portuguesa") when I heard the words **"uvas doiradas"**. Then I remembered that during my visits to Portugal I had heard similar vowel changes in other words such as **"touros"** and **"louras"** In Brazil I've never heard anyone say "toiros" or "doiradas". "Loiras" is not unusual and you may hear it, though. In Portugal I've heard both forms, **"ou"** and **"oi"**, and I wonder whether one of them is more prevalent?

**EM PORTUGUÊS**

Estava eu a ouvir (como bom brasileiro eu deveria dizer que "estava ouvindo") "Uma Casa Portuguesa", quando chamou-me a atenção os **"dois cachos de uvas doiradas"**.
Lembrei-me então de trocas vocálicas semelhantes: l**ou**ras x l**oi**ras, t**ou**ros x t**oi**ros, e d**ou**radas x d**oi**radas.  No Brasil nunca ouvi alguém falar "toiros" ou "doiradas".  Já "loiras" é falado por aqui, embora "louras" seja mais frequente. Em Portugal já ouvi as duas formas: **"ou"** e **"oi"**.  Qual a mais usada em Portugal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que o grupo *oi* em palavras com etimologia *ou* surgiu da [fala dos judeus](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-ditongos-ou-e-oi/2383) em Portugal e fica mais ou menos comum segundo região, por exemplo em Trás-os-Montes é mais comum ouvir *oi*.

Lembro que num dos meus livros sobre a poesia de Castro Alves, um poeta brasileiro, dizia que ele usava as formas de «aquele» então contemporâneas europeias (é do século XIX).  Como diz o sítio ligado, as formas alternavam-se num período após o descobrimento do Brasil, por isso, provavelmente teria sido mais difícil a incorporação da mudança na fala dos brasileiros, sobretudo se mesmo para os portugueses a pronúncia nunca chegou a ser o *standard*.

Comment: [Related](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/240/38)?

Comment: Corrigi *estándar* porque não conheço a palavra nem a encontrei no dicionário. Sabe-me dizer se existe * estándar*?

Comment: @JorgeB. Os problemas de falar três línguas muito parecidas... *Estándar* existe no castelhano e no asturiano, mas no português não. Imagino que seria melhor com *padrão* ou *geral*.