# Como se diz ''louco'' ou ''doido'' em português arcaico?

Tags: etimologia, português-europeu, tradução, origem-histórica, vocabulário

Estou fazendo a tradução de um texto em língua francesa em que consta o vocábulo ''fol'', variação arcaica de ''fou''.

Gostaria de saber, por favor, se há uma variação arcaica em língua portuguesa do vocábulo ''louco'', "doido"?

Answer (score 5):

Para variação arcaica, sugiro "**doudo**".
Tanto doido como doudo seriam versões aceites, mas doudo caiu em desuso.
Veja-se [a resposta de Yuuza](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/244/157) na pergunta sobre cabelos listada no fundo desta resposta.)

Isto tem a ver com as palavras com o ditongo "ou" terem também a alternativa "oi": ouro/oiro, touro/toiro, louro/loiro...

Para algumas, a forma "oi" tornou-se a primária: doido, coisa, noite.
Para outras, a forma "ou" tornou-se a primária: ouro, touro, tesouro.
Noutras, ambas são comuns: louro/loiro.

Na pergunta sobre "uvas douradas" ligaram para este artigo do Ciberdúvidas, que é esclarecedor e aconselho:

- https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-ditongos-ou-e-oi/2383

Ver também estas perguntas relacionadas:

- [Os cabelos são loiros ou louros?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/240)
- ["uvas douradas" or "uvas doiradas"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/uvas-douradas-or-uvas-doiradas)