# Qual a diferença entre "cousa" e "coisa"?

Tags: ortografia, significado, etimologia

O substantivo "cousa", palavra de uso antigo que é muito empregada na Bíblia, é apenas um sinônimo de "coisa" ou existe alguma diferença?

Ainda podemos usar "cousa" no lugar de "coisa"?

> Marcos 4.22
>   "Porque não há cousa alguma escondida que não venha a ser manifesta: nem cousa feita em oculto que não venha a ser pública."

Comment: Minha avó paterna escrevia "cousa",  mas não me recordo de algum dia ter ouvido alguém usar a palavra no português falado.

Comment: Relacionado: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/240/os-cabelos-s%C3%A3o-loiros-ou-louros/

Comment: Achei que "cousa" queria dizer algo parecido com "consta"

Comment: Muito legal a pergunta, Eu semprei pensei que cousa era uma forma errada de dizer coisa...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não há diferença semântica; é a mesma alternância *oi*/*ou* que ocorre em muitas outras palavras: *ouro*/*oiro*, *ouço*/*oiço*, *pousar*/*poisar* e por aí adiante, os ditongos geralmente representantes do *au* no étimo latino. Dado que *ou* não é sequer um ditongo na metade sul de Portugal e em todo o Brasil, *oi* permite conservar o ditongo.

No caso de *cousa*/*coisa*, ***coisa*** é muito mais comum modernamente. Por exemplo, o CETEMPúblico tem apenas 15 ocorrências (5 sem ser em citações) contra 14670 de *coisa*. Exemplo:

> *par=ext147942-nd-94b-1*: Mas prouvera a Deus, que destes lugares não tivera já passado alguma **cousa** também às igrejas.

Até há menos de um século, contudo, *cousa* era a forma preferida de alguns -- por exemplo, Said Ali (1861-1953) escrevia geralmente *cousa* e *dous*.

Comment: Isto se aplica no caso das "taubuas/tabuas"?

Comment: Creio que seja o mesmo caso de louro/loiro. Correto?